# How can I check if a variable is from this format? #string "......"?

Tags: bash

given a vriable `var` how can I check if `var` is from the following format:

> #string "......"

While instead of `.....` can be any other string?

I tried to compare it to this:  `"#string '"'*'"'"`  , but, it's not working.

Comment: Bash doesn't really have types in the way you seem to expect

Comment: @M.Becerra About what are you talking? for example, given `var=string "s"`  or `var=string "ssss"` or `var=string "sasafhasd"` , I want to get True..

Comment: `var=string "s"` is not bash

Comment: @M.Becerra string is not a type , only a characters. See exactly what I asked..

Comment: Can you define what would be a variable not composed by characters?

Comment: @M.Becerra Give me example in order to understand what you mean. But, `var=string "2412fax1!"` ok too.

Comment: Please add a few cases of which variables you would want to get a positive, **and** a few for which you would like to get a negative result

Comment: @M.Becerra I don't understand what is not clear in my question? I defined the template of variables that I want to get for them True.. What is the problem?

Comment: @Software_t You can't assign a value that way in bash (space aren't working around operands). So you can assign like that for example: `var="string \"blah\""` or like that `var="string blah"` but not `var=string "blah"`

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like:

```
[[ $var =~ ^#string\ \".*\"$ ]] && echo "ok" || echo "ko"
```

Demo:

```
$ var="#string \"blah\""
$ [[ $var =~ ^#string\ \".*\"$ ]] && echo "ok" || echo "ko"
ok
$ var="#int \"......\""
$ [[ $var =~ ^#string\ \".*\"$ ]] && echo "ok" || echo "ko"
ko
```

Comment: Can you explain what is the meaning of \ ?

Comment: It's only for escaping the double quotes to interpret those as characters.

Comment: And why you writed it twice after 'string' ?

Comment: @Software_t are you simply looking for this `$ [[ $var =~ ^#string\ .*$ ]] && echo "ok"`?